# Does trigger "see" all changes done in the transaction it was fired from?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, trigger, transaction

Let me elaborate on the title.

Suppose we have two tables, `t1` and `t2`. `t2` has a trigger `t2_trg`on it. Same transaction inserts/updates data in `t1`, then does insert/update in `t2`. `t2_trg` is fired and starts doing its thing. Is this trigger able to see all the changes done in `t1`?

P.s. I found other topics on this problem, but they we're mostly for SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, unless the trigger created with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular trigger  will see changes made in other tables within the same transaction. However, if you create the trigger (or other programmable object) with `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`, it will be executed within the scope of new transaction and won't be able to see "parent" transaction changes.

Comment: Do you have any links lying around on the topic?

Comment: Check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/autonotransaction_pragma.htm